# Using PDO and fetching links depending on usergroups

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Working with a CMS at the moment coded in PHP and i have encountered a small "hinderance".

I'm using a PDO(mysql) connection and i have two tables.

`Navigation_links` that have the following columns : `id`, `title` and `pageid`
`Navigation_links_usergroups_relations` with these columns : `linkid` and `usergroupid`

First and foremost i am trying to create a query that takes ALL of the links in which are NOT represented in the relations table. This is proving quite difficult for me. I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT navigation_links.id ,navigation_links.title, navigation_links.pageid 
  FROM navigation_links, navigation_links_usergroups 
 WHERE navigation_links.id != navigation_links_usergroups.linkid
```

Which in my mind translates to "Show all Links that don't exist in the relations table" as the links that aren't there should be visible to anyone.

Any suggestions or ideas? I'm quite sure that there is a way to do it. But maybe I'm attacking the problem from the wrong angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use correlation sub query, like this:

```
SELECT l.id, l.title, l.pageid
  FROM navigation_links AS l
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
           SELECT lug.* 
             FROM navigation_links_usergroups AS lug
            WHERE lug.linkid = l.id
       )
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i really needed. :)

Now i only need to make matching queries for links that only certain group ID's can see and i'm set.

Is it possible to search through an array of values to see if a user have the correct relations?

Ex. 'WHERE lug.usergroupid = IN(array(arrayofusergroupID that user have))'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.pageid
    FROM navigation_links n, navigation_links_usergroups nl 
        WHERE 
            n.id <> nl.linkid
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: it won't give him what he needs